# How to create standard combobox (select) in jquery ui style?

Tags: jquery-ui

[There is](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) combobox with autocomplete enabled. How to create combobox in the same style but without autocomplete (with just a few fixed values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you corectly you want not to allow user input and values shall be changed by click on button or textbox. For this purpose you can use "readonly" attribute like this:

```
input.attr("readonly", true);
```

Of course you my implement your widget and set it up by plugin options.