# How to disable jquery ui combobox?

Tags: jquery-ui

I use standard code taken from [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) page and try to disable combobox:

```
$( "#cbCountry" ).combobox({ disabled: true });
```

But it is still enabled. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the widget or disable the autocomplete?

Comment: I am trying to disable the widget. It is still should be visible. However I also have another question about disabling autocomplete - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650722/how-to-create-standard-combobox-select-in-jquery-ui-style ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code is for initializing a disabled combobox. If you want to disable an existing combobox, use this:

```
$("#cbCountry").combobox("option", "disabled", true);
```

**UPDATE**

Combobox is a separate jQuery UI widget, and it seems it does not implement these options. I was able to disable it by finding the text field and button inside the widget, and disabling those:

```
$("#cbCountry").closest(".ui-widget").find("input, button" ).prop("disabled", true)
```

Comment: I wanted to disable that during initialization. But if I use your code immediately after combobox creation, it doesn't work also.

Comment: Since 'combobox' is a special kind of autocomplete, try this after init: `$("#cbCountry").autocomplete("option", "disabled", true);`

Comment: It also doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, then I guess you'll have to do it the hard way... Will update my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Easy modification to combobox library to use:

```
$("#cbCountry").combobox('disable');
$("#cbCountry").combobox('enable');
```

In your combobox.js file add:

in **_create: function()** add local variable "a" (after `var input`, `a` ...).

Change `input = $("<input>")` to `input = this.input = $("<input>")`.

Change `a = $("<a>")` to `a = this.a = $("<a>")`.

Insert after `destroy`:

```
disable: function() {
    this.input.prop('disabled',true);
    this.input.autocomplete("disable");
    this.a.button("disable");
},
enable: function() {
    this.input.prop('disabled',false);
    this.input.autocomplete("enable");
    this.a.button("enable");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There is no need to use HTML and italic for code snippets, just indent them with spaces or use ``.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It helped me address a vexing last minute issue. :)

Answer (score 9):

I had to disable the combo box on click of button in my web application. Thanks to the people who have commented here. I was able to figure how to disable and enable the combo box as and when required. The code is as follows.

The below code is for disabling the combo box

```
$("#MyComboboxId").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input").autocomplete("option", "disabled", true).prop("disabled",true);
$("#MyComboboxId").parent().find("a.ui-button").button("disable");
```

The above JavaScript code finds the HTML elements for the ID and rest is explained in the above posts.

The below code is for enabling the combo box

```
$("#MyComboboxId").parent().find("input.ui-autocomplete-input").autocomplete("option", "disabled", false).prop("disabled",false);
$("#MyComboboxId").parent().find("a.ui-button").button("enable");
```

Comment: Your solution worked great in my case. I do not know why it does not have more ups.

Comment: I up'd this. This is the only solution that worked for me if wanting to disable combobox based on another combobox event (on change for example)