# Jquery-Mobile: how to enable select tag using name attribute in external java script

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Initially my select tag is set to disable mode in html. if you click on the select tag then i want to set to enable mode using onchange attribute. In onchange attribute i am calling the external java script function.it is working in general html with javascript. But it is not working in jquery mobile. please can anybody help me.Following is my code

```
< select id ="Item_Activity" size="1" disabled="disabled" onchange="Enable_ST(this)">< /select>
```

The code in external java script file is

```
Enable_ST(item)

{

  item.disabled = false; 

}
```

thanks

Comment: This is a bad question. Tidy up your code, and only show the relevant bits, nobody is going to want to read this

Comment: I edited the question. please see once.

Answer (score 0):

JQueryMobile generates span tags for its combo boxes, so disabling the "template" combo box is probably not going to do anything.

This is possibly similar to your issue, I realise its not JQM but rather Jquery UI, but the concepts should be similar: [How to disable jquery ui combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666441/how-to-disable-jquery-ui-combobox)

Effectively you are either going to have find the real HTML elements and disable them manually or you are going to have to call a JQM function to do it. I recommend the latter.