# Disable jQuery UI combobox

Tags: jquery, user-interface, combobox

I have a combobox in my page [(extension of jQuery UI autocomplete)](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).
And i want to disable them (the input field) at a method call.

I tried a variant of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666441/how-to-disable-jquery-ui-combobox), as

```
 $("#my_selector").next(".ui-combobox").find("input.ui-combobox-input").prop('disabled', true);
```

but it seems the span is not being fetched at all :( .

i had managed to set the input field's ID while _create() , directly accessing the input field as

```
 window.console.log("The ID ::" +$('#id_of_InputField_in_Autocomplete').attr('id'));
```

But this too returns *undefined*

Any inputs or some way to disable the field will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

According to the API at http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, the correct way to disable is:

```
$(".selector").autocomplete("disable");
```

or

```
$(".selector").autocomplete("option", "disabled", true);
```

Comment: True, but how do i get the $(".selector") ? :(
(which is in fact the _<input>_ field.)

Comment: jquery UI combobox plugin works by taking an existing <select> element in the page , hiding it and placing the <input> field next to t. (that is the _selector_ that we need). 

i had already tried to fetch the <input> field as explained in the question .But to no result !

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#my_selector').combobox('disable');
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately (wrap with backticks or add 4-space indentation) and add some annotation to the code.